# bookshelfJS: idAttribute to specify alternate id name

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I've added the idAttribute line to this code in hopes that it will allow me to specify an alternate name for my id field:

```
bookshelf.ApiUser = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    idAttribute: 'userID'
});
```

but it breaks my node project. As long as my id field is named 'id', the project works; how can I name the id field userID and have bookshelfjs know what to do?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. There is model.id and model.idAttribute, and I cant tell the difference, even after reading documentation ( http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-id )

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it breaks my node project"?

Comment: the project only works if the id field is named "id".

Comment: @DanPouliot - Can you provide a few things:  
  
(1) **The structure of your database table named `users`.**,
(2) **The snippet of code where you are using the ApiUser model.**
(3) **The errors returned.**

Comment: sorry, that was 6 months ago. I've moved on.

Comment: @sports, model.id is the actual id of a result or forged model, model.idAttribute is the field name that holds the id attribute, typically the primary key field.

Answer (score 2):

The value of idAttribute needs to be a column in the table. The purpose of it is to tell bookshelf which column it should use as the id field for thing like forge and relations. You cannot change the name of the field by specifying a different name there. The only way that I know how to change the field name in the model is to change the actual column name

**----- UPDATE ----**

Not that anyone cares, but you can work around this issue by using the virtual and hidden plugins to hide the actual id attribute and provide a virtual one with the different name.

first include the plugins

```
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf');
bookshelf.plugin('virtuals');
bookshelf.plugin('visibility');
```

then define your model with the id attribute as hidden and the virtual attribute to get/set the id attribute

```
bookshelf.ApiUser = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    hidden: ['id'],
    virtuals: {
        userID: {
            get: function() {
                return this.get('id');
            },
            set: function(value) {
                return this.set('id', value);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

you will still need the id field named 'id' in the database. or you can just rename the primary key in the database to userID.

Comment: Hi, not exactly related, but I wanted to ask about your bookshelf-pagemaker module if you don't mind .. I've been using Bookshelf a few months, and now am trying to get pagination queries using bookshelf-pagemaker. I was able to get basic pagination .. but not seeing how to give the query a simple WHERE clause. I was wondering if you have any suggestions on how to do this. Thanks for taking al look , Here's my post about this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/31374653/2162226